# Move signing subkey to authentication slot on YubiKey (OpenPGP card)?

Tags: key-management, gnupg, pgp, smartcard, yubikey

My PGP primary key is only used for certification—I use a separate subkey for signing. Like this:

```
sec  rsa4096/0x891781D0EDC66456                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     created: 2021-09-04  expires: never       usage: C                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
     trust: ultimate      validity: ultimate                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
ssb  rsa4096/0x14CF79D2D5917737                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     created: 2021-09-04  expires: 2023-09-04  usage: S                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
ssb  rsa4096/0x0041701689E0A409                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
     created: 2021-09-04  expires: 2023-09-04  usage: E                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
[ultimate] (1). test user <test@example.com>
```

I noticed that the OpenPGP card spec only supports three key slots: one for signing, one for encryption, and one for authentication. There is no slot dedicated to certification. However, the `keytocard` command permits moving the signing subkey to the authentication slot, and moving the certification key to the signature slot.

My question: Are there any downsides to moving the keys to the card (YubiKey) as follows:

- certification (primary) key to the signature slot
- signing subkey to the authentication slot
- encryption subkey to the encryption slot

In particular: Will I still be able to use the signing subkey for signing even though it's in the authentication slot? I generated some throwaway keys and it seemed to work, but I wanted confirmation that it was OK.

The YubiKey will mostly be in cold storage, used only for the occasional certification operations (e.g., extending subkey expiration) and as a backup if I lose my main YubiKey.